# how to Navigate GPS Co-ordinates into CameraView

Tags: ios, objective-c, navigation, core-location

i have indoor based location tracking task in camera view, currently i have all the room coordinates in my DB if user select any location from the list i have to open Camera and Navigate the arrow to the Destination Coordinates, i followed this tutorial for basic implementation : [enter link description here](https://www.invasivecode.com/weblog/a-simple-augmented-reality-engine-for-ios-devices/)

here my sample Code:

```
- (IBAction)start_action:(id)sender {

UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"navigation.png"];
arrowView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithImage:img];
UIImagePickerController*imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
imgPicker.delegate = self;
imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
imgPicker.showsCameraControls = NO;
imgPicker.cameraOverlayView = arrowView;
[self presentViewController:imgPicker animated:YES completion:nil];

}

 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation {

[self.locationMeasurements addObject:newLocation];


NSTimeInterval locationAge = -[newLocation.timestamp timeIntervalSinceNow];
if (locationAge > 5.0) {
    return;
}

if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy < 0) {
    return;
}


if (self.bestEffortAtLocation == nil || self.bestEffortAtLocation.horizontalAccuracy > newLocation.horizontalAccuracy) {

    _bestEffortAtLocation = newLocation;


    if (newLocation.horizontalAccuracy <= self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy) {

        [self stopUpdatingLocationWithMessage:NSLocalizedString(@"Acquired Location", @"Acquired Location")];

        [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(stopUpdatingLocationWithMessage:) object:nil];
    }
}


CLLocation *loc = _locationMeasurements.lastObject;

userCurrentLocation = _locationMeasurements.lastObject;

 userLat = userCurrentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
 userLon = userCurrentLocation.coordinate.longitude;
[self.locationManager startUpdatingHeading];

NSLog(@"lat  - %f and Long - %f",loc.coordinate.latitude,loc.coordinate.longitude);

}


 -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateHeading:(CLHeading *)newHeading{

 float poiLon = 13.044535;
 float poiLat = 80.268141;

float a = poiLon - userLon;
float b = poiLat - userLat;
float alpha = 180.0 * atan2(a, b) / M_PI;
if (alpha == 0.0)
    alpha += 360.0;
else if (alpha == 360.0)
    alpha -= 360.0;

CLLocationDirection theHeading = newHeading.trueHeading;
float deltaOrient = alpha - theHeading;
CGFloat X = 320.0/2.0 + (deltaOrient * 320.0f / 30.0);
CGFloat Y = 240;
[arrowView setCenter:CGPointMake(X, Y)];

 }
```

But the problem is the arrow is Pointing only in North West region only even though i switch to many GPS coordinates but still its showing same direction only how to fix this

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of coordinates than why you are doing all these calculation just to navigate the pin to the selected location. Just pass your selected coordinates to the below method. hope it will help you

```
-(void)loadMapViewWithCoordinates:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)startPoint
 {

    GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition 
    cameraWithLatitude:startPoint.latitude longitude:startPoint.longitude zoom:15.0];
    mapView.camera = camera;

}
```

Comment: bro iam talking about without MapView how u Navigate or create Object in Camera like ARKit